# Purpose of Batch Operations (enableBatchedOperations) in Topic/Subs in Azure Service Bus?

Tags: azureservicebus

I have a topic with two subscriptions. batchoperation is disabled at both topic level and subs level:

```
TopicDescription td = new TopicDescription(topicName);
td.setEnableBatchedOperations(false);
managementClient.createTopic(td);

SubscriptionDescription sd1 = new SubscriptionDescription(topicName, subOne);
sd1.setEnableBatchedOperations(false);

managementClient.createSubscription(sd1, somerule);

//2nd sub creation skipped
```

I verified these settings thru Service Bus Explorer.

However, I am still able to send messages to topic in batch mode using `TopicClient.sendBatch(Collection<? extends IMessage> messages)` method. And I am able to read messages from each Sub using `IMessageReceiver.receiveBatch(int maxMessageCount)`. How is this possible? Did I not understand the purpose of
enableBatchedOperations?

What is the purpose of enableBatchedOperations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you send a batch of messages, that's a client-side batching.
Entity level batching is designed to improve broker-side throughput with some added latency. See documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements#batching-store-access).